# jQuery's .html(): Is this a synchronization issue?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7, synchronization

I'm using jQuery 1.6.1 and I have some code that's erroring out in IE7, saying

```
Unexpected call to method or property access.
jquery.min.js, line 17 character 28710
```

That line is a call to

```
this.appendChild(a)
```

which is inside the .html() method.

My problem is that the code I have errors out when ran normally, but if I use IE's debugger and F10 (step) through the code, it works!  This leads me to believe it's a synchronization issue with the .html() method itself.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I think it will be much easier to help if you post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you are using .html() on HTML 5 elements in IE. You have to initialize an [HTML 5 shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) first. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) supports the Shiv plus many other useful features. Also have a look at [innverShiv](http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/) for setting innerHtml.